# How to Fix 'Module Not Found' Error When Creating Executable File with PyInstaller and Hidden Imports in Python?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

I am trying to create an executable file using pyinstaller. However, even after including my modules in hidden imports it still gives me the module not found error. Please help.

This the Error received

```
D:\>"D:\dist\Ookla samples extractor.exe"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Ookla samples extractor.py", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
[31948] Failed to execute script 'Ookla samples extractor' due to unhandled exception!
```

Tried the following commands:

```bash
pyinstaller -F "Ookla samples extractor.py"
pyinstaller -F --hidden-import=selenium "Ookla samples extractor.py"
py -m PyInstaller -F "Ookla samples extractor.py"
```

Also tried manually modifying the spec file and including the modules in hidden import.

```
a = Analysis(
    ['Ookla samples extractor.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=['selenium'],
    hookspath=[]
)
```

and then running the following command

```bash
py -m PyInstaller "D:\Ookla Samples Extractor.spec"
```

Comment: create a clean virtual environment, activate it, install selenium and pyinstaller then try again.